# Add an image into a select list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add an image into a select list:

```
<div class="popupbox">
    <div class="inside-out">
        <img src="images/cancel.png">

        <h5>Language<h5>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo"> English</option>
            <option value="saab"> Arabic</option>
            <option value="mercedes"> Indian</option>
            <option value="audi"> Indonesian</option>
        </select>

        <h5>Country<h5>
        <select>
            <option data-image="images/states.png"> Indonesia</option>
            <option value="saab"> America</option>
            <option value="mercedes"> Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="audi"> India</option>
        </select>

        <h5>Currency<h5>
        <select>
            <option value="volvo"> IDR - (RP)</option>
            <option value="saab"> USD - ($)</option>
            <option value="mercedes"> IRR - (IRR)</option>
            <option value="audi"> SAR - (SAR)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried `data-image=".png"` and I also tired using `background-image: url(.png)` but both don't work for me in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: You cannot add images to `option` elements. To do what you require you'd need to use a library which converts the `select` to another structure which can contain images, `ul`/`li` for example. Check out Select2

Comment: Do you want to show image besides the option values ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay yes exactly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how to do that?

Comment: https://select2.github.io/

Comment: You can check select2 of bootstrap.